# How to Find Spherical Mercator Points

Tags: html, openstreetmap

I am using Open Street Maps to show a map in my HTML5 application.

It uses a URL like this for the map tiles,

http://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/{Z}/{X}/{Y}.png

If I chose an area, say Auckland, New Zealand, how could I work out all of the values of Z, X, Y that would cover Auckland? I would be looking to write a script to go and grab all those images and cache them in an HTML5 database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, take a look at the [tile usage policy section about bulk download](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy#Bulk_Downloading). Secondly, this sort of caching is easily done using [TileStache](http://tilestache.org/): configure a cache to render or fetch tiles from a certain source, then run `tilestache-seed.py`, passing in the bounding box (in WGS84 coordinates) and desired zoom levels, and you should end up with all needed tiles.

Comment: Any documentation on how to configure the cache? Or preferable a walk through of some kind. Also I am running it in IIS on windows.

Comment: It says that it comes with it's own web server, Werkzeug, but when I run tilestache-server.py it says 'no module named wekzeug.serving'.

Comment: @peter there is some information on their [documentation page](http://tilestache.org/doc/). [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) is packaged separately, try to install it explicitly using `pip` or `easy_install`.